# How to create a heatmap with numbers using Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, clustering, heat-map, leaflet-draw

I wish to create a heatmap like this one at http://www.trulia.com/local/san-francisco-ca/tiles:1|points:1_crime

[image]

With the number changes at different zoom level - the number can appear in a mouse-hover window instead of directly showing on the map.

Any idea how to make this with Leaflet map?

EDIT:

I have a csv file with three columns:

```
    lat  lng  count
```

Any tips how to easily load it for 
[Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example it appears that they are using two techniques:

- the heatmap polygon layer is used to show the crime **risk**
- they are overlaying clustered points to show the **instances** of crime

So to emulate this effect, you would create a background layer/raster showing one variable from your dataset, and a point layer showing another variable, then [cluster the points](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

Comment: That's brilliant! I have updated my question. Any further tips how to load my csv file for  Leaflet.markercluster?

Comment: it'd be best to ask that as a separate question